# Check if the device has an application to pick "media/*" from Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm developing an application that allows the user to pick an image from the gallery, but I want to be able to select images or videos when possible.

So far if I change:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("image/*");
```

to:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("media/*");
```

The option to choose it from gallery is not visible, but other programs show up (like ASTRO)

Is there any way to detect programmatically whether the device has other program to select media/* or not, so I can choose what type I'm going to set in the Intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) with this intent to know which applications handle this content type.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("media/*");
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<resolveinfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

From there, you can check the list size, or if list contains a given package name, and do te appropriate action.

Comment: In a related topic, I wrote a blog post about [how to pick up the default twitter client](http://regis.decamps.info/blog/2011/06/intent-to-open-twitter-client-on-android/)